# Store temporary data outside of iOS app

Tags: ios, caching, app-store

I have an app that is uniquely branded for each customer (think restaurants, etc.) I need to have the user be able to click on a link to my server that contains a unique code, stores that temporarily on the iOS device (cookie, etc.) and then directs them to the app store to download the app. Then when it is downloaded, the app grabs that cookie or temp. data on launch and brands the app for that customer. I know this is possible on Android, but is it on iOS?

Downloading the app first and then selecting the brand (or restaurant) is not feasible in this case, as the url wil be shared with other customers of the same business and we want to create a fluid experience, where they won't be able to "see behind the scenes" and choose a different branding.

Thanks

**Edit**
Thank you for all the replies. We've reevaluated and are considering having the url be opened on the device and grabbing the IP address or another unique id, and saving that along with the correct brand to a database. The app will then connect to the database on launch, and if the IP's match, will brand accordingly. We're looking for a more reliable identifier than IP, however. Now that UDID is deprecated, are there any other identifiers we can use?

Comment: Unfortunatly, the App Store guidelines explicitly prohibits the downloading of additional code from the internet to run within your app.

Comment: Unless the app is dynamically branded after install, you'll have to submit numerous version to the app store which *might* cause you approval problems.
If you can pre-supply your users with a user name and password, you could have the app be branded on first login.

Comment: @harrym17: it needn't necessarily be additional code as such. Rather images for company logos and strings of text for labelling, etc.

Comment: So how does this work if you have multiple clients in market (say two restaurants), and the customer tries to download your app for both of them? I don't see how this can be made into a good user experience even if you could identify the user.

Comment: @RobNapier We're not worried about that. Fewer than 1% of our users will ever need multiple brands. If a different brand is needed, it will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: You've got the advertising ID. Less reliable (because it can be reset), but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the design you propose of a webserver link creating the code that needs to be read by the iOS app later is the issue.  You should have a solution that is entirely app based.  Perhaps you can have the same services on the website be available as one app which then sets up the code in pasteboard.  The user then launches the actual app that looks at the pasteboard and skins itself accordingly.

That being said, data can be shared between apps from the same app seed ID by using [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) in addition to a few other ways.

I use the pasteboard to share info between apps quickly and easily using this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use identifierForVendor (UDID replacement) to identify individual devices. Are you planning on harvesting those identifiers prior to the end user "registering" the device at the final location? If not you'll never be able to determine which device belongs where.

What about having the end-user logging into your server as that restaurant? It can be a somewhat generic login per restaurant like "Wendys/Wendys5?" and "McDonalds/McDonalds7!" to determine their App Store URL. As long as the password is easy and non-programmatic to guess it would be unlikely they figure out how to register as a different restaurant. You could also do a simple restaurant selection screen coupled with a password specific to each chain but this would expose the user to which other restaurants are using the app. This way you won't have to continually add IPs if they expand locations and can revoke credentials if the login is compromised.

One question, though: Do all of your clients understand that they'll have to have an AppleID tied to each device? You can only shared a single AppleID across 20 devices.